# Fastest way to split a large list of integers into List of strings in C#

Tags: c#

My goal is to split a list of 24043 integers into strings like:

**"?ids=" + "1,2,3...198,199,200"**

Can you think of a better solution than mine in terms of performance?

```
    public List<string> ZwrocListeZapytan(List<int> listaId)
    {
        var listaZapytan = new List<string>();

        if (listaId.Count == 0) return listaZapytan;

        var zapytanie = "?ids=";
        var licznik = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < listaId.Count; i++)
        {
            if (licznik == 200 || i == listaId.Count - 1)
            {
                listaZapytan.Add(zapytanie + listaId[i]);
                zapytanie = "?ids=";
                licznik = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                zapytanie += listaId[i] + ",";
                licznik++;
            }
        }
        return listaZapytan;
    }
```

Comment: Use `StringBuilder` class instead concatenate strings. This should improve performace and memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you think of a better solution than mine in terms of performance?

It terms of performance the only thing that comes to my mind as an enhancement for your code is to use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) when you concatenate the string:

```
public List<string> ZwrocListeZapytan(List<int> listaId)
{
    var listaZapytan = new List<string>();

    if (listaId.Count == 0) return listaZapytan;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("?ids=");        

    var licznik = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < listaId.Count; i++)
    {    
        if (licznik == 200 || i == listaId.Count - 1)
        {
            listaZapytan.Add(sb.ToString() +listaId[i]);
            sb.Clear();
            sb.Append("?ids=");
            licznik = 1;    
        }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(listaId[i] + ",");
        licznik++;
    }        return listaZapytan;
}
```

Otherwise you could make the for-loop run in steps of the 200. At each step take the numbers from the given range and use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the string:

```
// TEST DATA
List<int> listaId = Enumerable.Range(1, 420).ToList();

List<string> listaZapytan = new List<string>();
int stepsize = 200;

for (int i = 0; i < listaId.Count; i +=stepsize)
{
    listaZapytan.Add("?ids=" + String.Join(",", listaId.Skip(i).Take(stepsize)));
}
```

Comment: I like your solution. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot that 0 % 200 is 0. Actually, that was my first idea and I solved this problem by adding that extra counting variable.

Comment: @gutowskiap you are right. Fixed it by `((i > 0 && i % 200 == 0)`

Comment: Now you skipped 321 out of 24043 ids.

Comment: @gutowskiapI switched to your original way of counting with a second variable. This way there is a working code posted. :) The second solution should work thoroughly though

Comment: Yes, I'm going with second solution because I'm not a fan of Linq.

Answer (score 3):

**Using Linq:**

Assuming `listaId` is the list of integers that has to be converted:

```
var result = listaId.GroupBy(x => x / 200)
    .Select(y => "?ids=" + string.Join(",", y)).ToList();
```

- `.GroupBy()` helps take 200 at a time
- `.Select()` is used to combine them together in the format like the OP suggested i.e `?ids=1,2,...` using `string.Join()`

Comment: This is a good answer. Although, you'll wanna use 201 instead of 200.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne using 201 will not work correctly. The third set will start from 603. The solution assumes OP's list starts from 1 onwards like he's mentioned: 1,2,... 24043. Using x / 200, the output comes out to 1-199, 200-399, and so on. Take a look here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lyPXIN

Comment: This is very elegant solution, but I'm not a fan of Linq. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you please make a try with this and let me know whether this approach helps to solve your issue?

```
    List<int> listaId = Enumerable.Range(0, 24043).ToList();

    var items = String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, 24043)
                                          .Select((x,i)=>i%200==0?
                                           "\n?ids=" + x.ToString():
                                           "," + x.ToString()));
```

[Running Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gyw4D4)

Here we are using `Enumerable.Range` to generate `24043` continuous numbers starting from `0`. Then we can use the `Select` method to split them into a list of `200` and form the required string. If you want to get the output as a List, Remove the String.Join and add `.ToList()` at the end of the query. Current query produces output with `0-199` in the first list if you want `200` in that list means change the condition to `i%201`.